# How can I add an icon and a subtitle to a Joomla menu item?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

In Joomla 3.2 I need a to show a group of "buttons" (colored boxes) that are links to other articles or pages. These buttons must have an icon, a title (with bold text and a larger font) and a subtitle with a smaller font.

It's possible to do this with the standard menu component and some CSS customization, or shall I install or create a new component? If so, do you know any component that does this things?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also confused once to find the simple solution to attach an icon to menu-item links, but it was in version 2.5.12

The solution for version 3.0 and above is also same.

While adding a menu item you will find another tab with heading "Advanced Options"

In that you will find "Link Type Options" Tab.

```
  "Advanced Options"-> "Link Type Options"
```

From that you can set "Link Image" and the image will get attached to the same menu item.

```
 "Advanced Options"-> "Link Type Options"->"Link Image"
```

You do not need to use any other extensions if the requirements are paused at menu-item icons only and you can use tool-tip option to inform users more about the links, I think sub-title is not possible to set here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's interesting, but I also need the subtitle (and it's mandatory).

Comment: Okay, let me check for the solution, it would be easier for me if you send a pictorial view of what you want exactly and where you want that sub-title exactly!!!

Comment: 1 more solution i can suggest you.
You can see the "Note" field in Details tab, which we use rarely at front-end.
You can get the value of that field and set it as the subtitle with your menu item links.

Comment: I need to create a menu of images like this: [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/mwb7fp.png)

Comment: Yupps, Got the point, I think you can use the way i suggested you in my previous comment.
Try to get use of that Note field and set it as your subtitle.
I think you will get done with it.